# Make element visible in different breakpoints

Tags: vue.js, element-plus

I would like hide and show elements in different breakpoints. For example I could use v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.md" in the [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/). How i can do this in the [element-plus](https://element-plus.org/en-US/)?

I can use classes but is there any other solution?

> hidden-xs-only - hide when on extra small viewports only

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution -> breakpoints in @vueuse.

https://vueuse.org/core/useBreakpoints/

Answer (score 0):

You can use utility classes for hiding the elements: [offical docs](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/layout.html#utility-classes-for-hiding-elements).